# Drupal 7 replacing texfield loses ajax functionality

Tags: ajax, forms, drupal

I'm having some problems with the ajax function in Drupal 7.
When I use the ajax command replace function to replace a form textfield, it loses its ajax functionality.

Example:

Form build:

```
function ds_check_post_new_data_import($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['txt1'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', 
        '#size' => 2,
        '#value' => "val1", 
        '#name' => "txt1",
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'ajax_test_callback2',
        ),
        '#prefix' => '<div id="txt1">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
    $form['txt2'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', 
        '#size' => 2,
        '#value' => "val2",  
        '#name' => "txt2",
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'ajax_test_callback2',
        ),
        '#prefix' => '<div id="txt2">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );

    return $form;
}
```

The ajax callback:

```
function ajax_test_callback2($form, &$form_state) {

    $form['txt1'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', 
        '#size' => 2,
        '#value' => "ajaxed1", 
        '#name' => "txt1",
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'ajax_test_callback2',
        ),
        '#prefix' => '<div id="txt1">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
    $form['txt2'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', 
        '#size' => 2,
        '#value' => "ajaxed2",  
        '#name' => "txt2",
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'ajax_test_callback2',
        ),
        '#prefix' => '<div id="txt2">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );

    return array(
        '#type' => 'ajax',
        '#commands' => array(
            ajax_command_replace("#txt1", render($form['txt1'])),
            ajax_command_replace("#txt2", render($form['txt2']))
        )
    );
}
```

Now, when I change the value in the first textfield, both are replaced, that's fine. But when I change the value again the ajax functionality is gone.

Somebody got the same problem?

Before you ask me why I wanna do this:

*Actually I have a custom table theme, that renders some rows, and on each row there are three textfields (rendered with custom theme table..)
When the user changes something in the first textbox, the other two have to be changed based on the entered value.
Then when the user changes the value in the second textfield, the other two have to be updated.*

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0):

you should be doing all the form building inside the form build function. Including any changes when the ajax callback is called.

```
function ds_check_post_new_data_import($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['wrap'] = array(
        '#markup' => '',
        'prefix' => '<div id="field-wrapper">',
        'suffix' => '</div>',
    );
    $form['wrap']['txt1'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', 
        '#size' => 2,
        '#value' => "val1", 
        '#name' => "txt1",
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'ajax_test_callback2',
            'wrapper' => 'field-wrapper',
        ),
    );
    $form['wrap']['txt2'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', 
        '#size' => 2,
        '#value' => "val2",  
        '#name' => "txt2",
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'ajax_test_callback2',
            'wrapper' => 'field-wrapper',
        ),
    );

    // Here check if it has been called via ajax, check something in
    // $form_state, I forget what.
    // Its something like $form_state['submitted'] or $form_state['input']
    // If true, set values
    if (ajax called) {
        $form['wrap']['txt1']['#value'] = 'ajaxed1';
        $form['wrap']['txt2']['#value'] = 'ajaxed2';
    }

    return $form;

}

function ajax_test_callback2($form, &$form_state) {
    // return the element that contains both testfields.
    // no need to create a $command, it defaults to replace.
    return $form['wrap'];
}
```

I am not sure why you are calling the same callback function from both textfields, so I will give an example where they each call their own function

```
function ds_check_post_new_data_import($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['txt1'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', 
        '#size' => 2,
        '#value' => "val1", 
        '#name' => "txt1",
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'ajax_test_callback1',
            'wrapper' => 'txt1',
        ),
        '#prefix' => '<div id="txt1">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
    $form['txt2'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', 
        '#size' => 2,
        '#value' => "val2",  
        '#name' => "txt2",
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'ajax_test_callback2',
            'wrapper' => 'txt2',
        ),
        '#prefix' => '<div id="txt2">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );

    // Here check if it has been called via ajax, check something in
    // $form_state, I forget what.
    // Its something like $form_state['submitted'] or $form_state['input']
    // If true, set values
    if (ajax called on first field) {
        $form['txt1']['#value'] = 'ajaxed1';
    }
    if (ajax called on second field) {
        $form['txt2']['#value'] = 'ajaxed2';
    }

    return $form;
}

function ajax_test_callback1($form, &$form_state) {
    // no need to create a $command, it defaults to replace.
    return $form['txt1'];
}

function ajax_test_callback2($form, &$form_state) {
    // no need to create a $command, it defaults to replace.
    return $form['txt2'];
}
```

**NOTE: these are untested**, but you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually replacing elements that have JS events bound to them, you will need to rebind the events after the replacement. Drupal has a great Behaviors system integrated to specifically handle this when AJAX happens to replace elements on the page. If you've got custom JS in there (which it sounds like you do), be sure that the events get rebound if the elements are being replaced.

Comment: If he does have custom js he should probably be using `ajax_command_invoke`